# How to determine the infinite limit: $\lim_{x \to (\pi/2)^+} (6/x) \sec(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> Determine the infinite limit (either $-\infty$ or $\infty$):
>   $$\lim_{x \to (\pi/2)^+} \frac{6}{x} \sec(x).$$

My work:

Since the period of secant is $2\pi$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ has to be somewhere in the beginning of the period. Using graphing utility it gives me

[image: Plot]

Since secant has a period of $2\pi$, the point $\frac{\pi}{2}$ has to be at about the first quarter of the graph and since we're asked too approach from $\frac{\pi^+}{2}$. If we look at it's first quarter the graph seems to increase infinitely. I do not understand why the answer is positive inifinity. I would appreciate if you could dumb it down to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that the main problem here comes from the $\sec$ function, since
$$\frac{6}{x}\to\frac{12}{\pi} \quad\text{ as }\quad x\to\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Regarding $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, you have a singularity in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$, so it is clear that the whole limit will be either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Therefore, to determine the sign you need to focus on the sign of $\cos(x)$ around $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Is it negative or positive for $x$ (slightly) bigger than $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Finally, the sign of $\sec(\frac{\pi}{2}^+)$ is the same as for $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}^+)$ and, since $\frac{6}{(\pi/2)^+}>0$, also for the hole limit.